# Is there a way to share content between users?

Tags: nodes, privatemsg

Drupal 7... I just want to be able to send some information via content type from one user to the next such as an event. One user will create this content and only wants it seen by a select few of other users. Is there a way to make this happen. What would be cool is a field on my content type that collects usernames or emails for a private message or invite to view the content...

Comment: is there a way to alter the private message hook to allow such a field through custom mod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find that the [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) module is very useful for allowing users to protect content in this way.  You may configure og such that only certain users may create groups, or if you prefer, as in the use case you describe above, many users may be allowed to create new groups for diverse purposes. There are many options on inviting users to groups, allowing users to request memberships to groups, or just letting anyone join groups automatically. It looks to me as if the behaviour you want can be achieved with just the og module, but if that is not the case, there are also many additional contrib modules that can extend or modify og's behavior.